# Simple reshape of numpy array: error: 'total size of new array must be unchanged'

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, numpy-ndarray

Here is a very straightforward version of the problem i am having reshaping a 40*1 array into a 20*2 array. What is going wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(1,20,40)
#confirm length is 40
print(np.shape(x))
#reshape to 2*20
print(np.reshape(x,2,20))
#returns error: 'total size of new array  must be unchanged'
```

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: You haven't read the docs closely enough

Comment: @seralouk yes, it answers my question exactly. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not use the function as you should use it.

Simply use this:

```
np.reshape(x,(2,20))
```

[Documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

**Full code:**

```
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(1,20,40)
#confirm length is 40
print(np.shape(x))
print(np.reshape(x,(2,20)))
```